# Send Array of Objects to C++ client with Node.Js server

Tags: arrays, node.js, sockets

I am trying to send an array of objects to my C++ client using the code below. I originally was trying to do so with just the http library alone in which i further investigated and found this out to be not correct approach.

What i'm not clear with this is  how socket.write("hello C++ client") will allow me to send this string and have it appear in my terminal C++ but using socket.emit("arrayTransfer", arrayOfObjects); or a similar variation of what i'm trying below will not allow me to receive anything, I have tried different variations of sending the array of objects but have not succeeded can someone help me understand what exactly may be going on in this code and how Nodejs handles these types of sockets? 
thank you.

Here is my questions I asked before to gain a better understanding perhaps.
[NodeJs server and C++ client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067105/nodejs-server-and-c-client)

```
var server = require("net").createServer();
var io = require("socket.io")(server);


    socket.emit("message", myArray[0].name);
};

io.on("connection", handleClient);

server.listen(8080);
```

**C++ CLIENT CODE BELOW**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#define LENGTH (512)

#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define PORT_NUMBER (8080) // port number where to port in application

int clientSocket;
char buffer[LENGTH];
struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
socklen_t addr_size;




int main()
{

    /*---- Create the socket. The three arguments are: ----*/
    /* 1) Internet domain 2) Stream socket 3) Default protocol (TCP in this case) */
    clientSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    /*---- Configure settings of the server address struct ----*/
    /* Address family = Internet */
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    /* Set port number, using htons function to use proper byte order */
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUMBER);

    /* Set IP address to localhost */
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    /* Set all bits of the padding field to 0 */
    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);

    /*---- Connect the socket to the server using the address struct ----*/
    addr_size = sizeof serverAddr;
    connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, addr_size);

    /*---- Read the message from the server into the buffer ----*/



    recv(clientSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);
    printf("This is your message %s", buffer);





    close(clientSocket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you include your c++ client code as well

Comment: Certainly, please see the bottom of my original post

Comment: where is the `handleClient` method in the server code?